Body contorting when I try to pose it
I'm trying to manually rig a model but when I turn the head, the head starts to contort and shift to become smaller/skinnier. How can I fix this??


Hello, probably its vertices are assigned to a bad vertex group, maybe share your file?

@moonboots Added file to the post!

If you select a vertex of the head, you can read its weights assignements in the "N" properties panel, and discover that head vertices are also weighted to something like a root bone, that it's causing the distorsion.
To solve uncheck the "Deform" option of that bone, or delete its weights assignements.

